# threading and sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I am having a problem understanding how sleep works. For example in Java, if I have a Thread and write:

```
try{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
  catch(exception e){//something}
  finally{ someFunction();}
```

as I understand it, in this code, the threadf sleeps for one second and then performs someFunction. But why doesn't this work:

```
try{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   someFunction();
   }
  catch(exception e){//something}
```

Surely in this code, the processor "sleeps" for a seocnd and then performs someFunction(). But that's not hwo it works. I would like to know why?

Comment: "But that's not hwo it works." so what difference in behaviour are you experiencing?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality of the two statements is exactly the same as long as an exception is not thrown -- the only difference between the two is that the `finally` block will be executed if an exception is thrown in the try block.

Comment: finnaly block will be executed not only if an exception is thrown. "The finally block always executes when the try block exits."http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 1):

To quote the javadoc:

> Throws InterruptedException - if another thread has interrupted the current thread.

When your thread is not interrupted the two blocks of code are qequivalent, but you cannot know whether you will be interrupted or not, so to be sure your code is correct in both circumstances you should handle the `InterruptedException` (to either ignore or sleep again of not enough time has passed.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) on the finally block:

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.
>
> **Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.**

So, ideally there should be no difference between the behavior of the two blocks of code. But it would help if you could share more details about what is different.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example the `someFunction()` will be executed always, even if the `try` block raises an `exception`. In that case, the `exception` block will be executed first and then the `finally` block. If no `exception` is raised then the `finally` block will be executed after the execution of the `try` block.

In the second code example the `someFunction()` will not be executed if the `sleep()` method will fail. Then the `exception` block is executed and the lines of code after the `sleep()` method will be skipped.